# How can I click on a button specific to its column name for different rows on a webtable

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

How can do I  click on  Add button using the specific name from Column1 for different rows on a webtable using selenium webdriver.

The webtable is as

```
Row 1|column1| Column2| Add Button
Row 2|column1| Column2| Add Button
Row 3|column1| Column2| Add Button
Row 4|column1| Column2| Add Button
```

I have added some users and now I want to click on the add button depending upon the name of the user, the name of the users may vary so I want to store the name in an arraylist and then depending on the name stored want to click on the add button to enter some details for that particular user.

Comment: The below code helps me in finding all the columns names as per the row. WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='jtable']")); 
 List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
 WebElement tRow= rows.get(2);

Comment: //System.out.println(tRow.getText()); 
 List<WebElement> allCells = tRow.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
 System.out.println("Total rows "+ rows.size()); 
 System.out.println("Total cols "+ allCells.size()); 
 for(int rNum=0;rNum<rows.size();rNum++){ 
 WebElement currentRow = rows.get(rNum); 
 allCells = currentRow.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
 for(int cNum=0;cNum<allCells.size();cNum++){ 
 System.out.print(allCells.get(cNum).getText() +" --- "); 
 } 
 System.out.println(); 
 }

Comment: Can you provide the html code? I think you should be able to click via xpath

Comment: You will need to use xpath identifiers. First, you need one to identify the row for a particular user name; and secondly, a [relative xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) which can identify the Add button on that row. Then you can plug those identifiers into the findElement function to locate the right button. Have a play with [firepath](https://code.google.com/p/firepath/) to get the hang of the xpaths.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not enough good at JAVA. But following logic will help you to write Java code:

```
table = driver.find_element(:id, "table_id")
rows = table.find_elements(:tag_name, "tr")
len = rows.length 

len.times do |i|
    if table.find_element(:xpath, "//tr[#{i+1}]/td[2]/div").text.eql? "expected_text"
        table.find_element(:xpath, "//tr[#{i+1}]/td[4]/div").click
    end
end
```

Here is a Java code (might be syntactically incorrect). Try it:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("table_id"));
// WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class="jtable"]"));  (for your case)
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int i=0; i<rows.length(); i++ ){
    if(table.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[#{i+1}]/td[2]/div").getText == "expected_text"){
       table.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[#{i+1}]/td[4]/div")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone provide a java code for clicking on the add button as per the column1 for each row.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do that :

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.jtable"));
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for (WebElement row : rows) {
  if(row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:nth-child(2)")).getText().equals("expected name"))
  row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:last-child input")).click();
}
```

[Take a look here to see how cssSelector works with my exemple.](http://jsfiddle.net/Yv5rd/1/)

PS : if you want to compare 2 strings, you must use `.equals()` not `==`